# How to make a proper cartesian graph using WinRT XAML Toolkit?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

Currently my graphs look like this;

[image]

While I want them to look something like this

[image]

(As in, dual-sided axes on both sides)

Is it possible to do with WinRT XAML Toolkit? I can't figure out how to make these Cartesian graphs using Lineseries. Will this automatically happen if I make a linearaxis with a range of values of negative to positive (and if so I'd appreciate if someone would show me how to do this)?

```
<Charting:Chart x:Name="LineChart" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="600" Height="400">
        <Charting:LineSeries            
           Title="Smartphone Companies" Margin="0" IndependentValuePath="Time" DependentValuePath="Amount" IsSelectionEnabled="True"/>
        </Charting:Chart>
```

Comment: Someone help, maybe? :(